# Css Square Bangles Shape Div

Tags: html, css

Anyone Can please help me to make this div like square bangle shape

like this

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? Do you have an code to show?

Comment: i tried using border radius but it doesn't work what i need.


I want my border radius same as blue border shape

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.main
{
border-top-left-radius:50px 50px;
border-top-right-radius:50px 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius:50px 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius:50px 50px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:orange;" class="main">
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element for layering two shapes above each other like this:

```css
.x {
position: relative;
left: 50px;
top: 50px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 240px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px 130px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px 130px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 130px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 130px;
  border: 30px solid #af8;
}
.x:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -20px;
top: -40px;
width: 240px;
height: 260px;
  border-top-left-radius: 130px 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 130px 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 130px 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 130px 15px;
  border: 30px solid #af8;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

And if you want similarly rounded corners on the inner shape too, you can put another element plus an additional pseudo element on top of it:

```css
.x {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 240px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px 130px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px 130px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 130px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 130px;
  border: 30px solid #af8;
}

.x:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -40px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  border-top-left-radius: 130px 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 130px 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 130px 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 130px 15px;
  border: 30px solid #af8;
}

.y {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 5px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 260px;
  border-top-left-radius: 130px 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 130px 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 130px 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 130px 10px;  
  border: none;
  background: #eee;
}
.y:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: -5px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px 130px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px 130px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 130px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 130px;  
  border: none;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="y"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope this is not bro check the curve its little bit different in shape its just like square bangles its square but sides are little curve.

Comment: please note my changed answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that it's what you want, but did you try clip-path? You can cut from inside and corners (use paths or svg). Something like that:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 75%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 85% 100%, 100% 85%, 100% 15%, 85% 0%, 15% 0%, 0% 15%, 0% 85%, 15% 100%, 85% 100%, 75% 75%);
clip-path: polygon(25% 75%, 25% 25%, 75% 25%, 75% 75%, 85% 100%, 100% 85%, 100% 15%, 85% 0%, 15% 0%, 0% 15%, 0% 85%, 15% 100%, 85% 100%, 75% 75%);
```